# Draw a vertical line in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to draw a line vertical line in my wp8 c# project.
I already have a horizontal line but I can't figure out how to get the vertical line.
How can I draw a vertical line?

This is my horizontal line

```
 <Line Stretch="Fill" StrokeDashArray="4,1" Stroke="Black" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0"/>
```

Comment: Set `X2` same as `X1` and set `Y2` higher than `Y1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

X1 and X2 changes the values horizontally, draws a horizontal line 
For drawing a vertical line you need to change Y values keeping that X fixed ...

```
<Line Stretch="Fill" StrokeDashArray="4,1" Stroke="Black" X1="0"  Y2="100"/>
```

Check if this works.